# react native text justify and center

Tags: react-native, text-align

In react native we have textAlign property with the options to either "justify" (and the last line will follow default text direction) or "center" (where the text is centered but lines are not justified)
I want to know if there is a way to combine both (i.e. center the text and also have the lines start and end uniformly)?

Edit:
Here is the code
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView, StatusBar } from "react-native";

```
export default function App() {
 return (
  <View style={styles.background}>
  <View style={styles.pageContainer}>
    <ScrollView
      contentContainerStyle={{
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Text style={styles.arabicText}>
        هنا ستكون الآيات (1) هنا ستكون الآيات (1) هنا ستكون الآيات (1) هنا
        ستكون الآيات (1) هنا ستكون الآيات (1) هنا ستكون الآيات (1) هنا ستكون
        الآيات (1) هنا ستكون الآيات (1) هنا ستكون الآيات (1) هنا ستكون
        الآيات (1) هنا ستكون الآيات (1) هنا ستكون الآيات (1) هنا ستكون
        الآيات (1) هنا ستكون الآيات (1) هنا ستكون الآيات (1) هنا ستكون
        الآيات (1) هنا ستكون الآيات (1) هنا ستكون الآيات (1) هنا ستكون
        الآيات (1) هنا ستكون الآيات (1)
        </Text>
       </ScrollView>
     </View>
    </View>
  );
 }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: "space-evenly",
  alignItems: "center",
  backgroundColor: "white",
  },
  pageContainer: {
  alignItems: "center",
  width: "100%",
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: "#FFFAF1",
},
 arabicText: {
 direction: "rtl",
 marginRight: 8,
 marginLeft: 8,
 marginTop: 5,
 marginBottom: 5,
 flexDirection: "row",
 textAlign: "justify",
 fontSize: 26,
  padding: 2,
  },
});
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can put your `Text` tag inside `View` tag and give your View `alignItems:'center'`
property

```
 <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
    <Text style={{ textAlign: 'justify' }}>
         Enter your text here
    </Text>
 </View>
```

Comment: thank you for the response, but it is not working (I want the text itself to start from the right of the line, so it should be something like "justify & right" mode in text but I don't know if this is possible in react native)
I added the code for more clarification